# How to make one by one counting - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to make this counter one by one. Ex: Count1 end the counting Count2 will start if count2 end-up count-3 will start counting. If all 4 counting finish again it start loop from Count1.

```js
$('.count').each(function anim() {
$(this).prop('Counter',0).animate({
    Counter: $(this).text()
}, {
    duration: 2000,
    easing: 'swing',
    step: function (now) {
        $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
    },
    complete: function(){
        $(this).css('counter',0);
        setTimeout(anim.bind(this),5000);
    }
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="counter inner">
        <ul>
          <!--Count1-->
          <li>
              <h5 class="count count1">35</h5>
              <p>Years</p>
          </li>
          <!--Count2-->
          <li>
              <h5 class="count count2">150</h5>
              <p>Employees</p>
          </li>
          <!--Count3-->
          <li>
              <h5 class="count count3">15</h5>
              <p>Branches</p>
          </li>
          <!--Count4-->
          <li>
              <h5 class="count count4">1500</h5>
              <p>Clients</p>
          </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: so what is the question?

Comment: @singhakash did you downvotes me?

Comment: no I din't downvote you

Comment: Ok fine. I got ans. Thanks for ur time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$('.count').eq(0).each(anim);

function anim() {
  $(this).prop('Counter', 0).animate({
    Counter: $(this).text()
  }, {
    duration: 2000,
    easing: 'swing',
    step: function(now) {
      $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
    },
    complete: function() {
      if($(this).parent().next().prop("tagName") == "LI"){
        $(this).parent().next().find(".count").each(anim);
      }
      else{
        $('.count').eq(0).each(anim);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="counter inner">
  <ul>
    <!--Count1-->
    <li>
      <h5 class="count count1">35</h5>
      <p>Years</p>
    </li>
    <!--Count2-->
    <li>
      <h5 class="count count2">150</h5>
      <p>Employees</p>
    </li>
    <!--Count3-->
    <li>
      <h5 class="count count3">15</h5>
      <p>Branches</p>
    </li>
    <!--Count4-->
    <li>
      <h5 class="count count4">1500</h5>
      <p>Clients</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Triggers function `anim` on the first `count` element, then trigger next in `complete` function.